# Python split list based on difference

Tags: python

I have a list like this

```
a = [10,20,20,24,25,80,90,100,100,101,102,103,140,141,142,143,120,110,100,90,50,40,0]
```

I need to iterate each consecutive element and pick those elements which are within the range of difference (say 4).

For this example following Segments should be created

Yes keep adding elements if they are within the range else ignore .

```
[20,24,25] [100,101,102,103] [140,141,142,143] [0,0]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything buddy?

Comment: What happens for `10, 13, 15, 17`?

Comment: Did you try to iterate through the array and if the difference is more than what you need, yield the accumulated entries?

Comment: And what if you have `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]` would this evaluate to one list, even though `16` and `10` are more than 4 apart?  And what about `11` since it could be included in `[10, 11, 12, 13]` and `[11, 12, 13, 14]` etc...

Comment: Yes that would be 1 list [10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it looks like you want something like:

```
def groupit(seq, thresh=4, minlen=3):
    itr = iter(seq)
    accum = [next(itr)]
    while True:
        newone = next(itr, None)
        if newone is None: break
        if abs(newone - accum[-1]] <= thresh:
            accum.append(newone)
        else:
            if len(accum) >= minlen: yield accum
            accum = [newone]
    if len(accum) >= minlen: yield accum

result = list(groupit(seq))
```

However in your desired results you show one last group of `[0, 0]` that comes out of the blue without any justification or explanation -- no idea what that's meant to signify.  This code does **not** have that one last, apparently totally arbitrary group, only the real ones.